Wordpress post meta key and value lookup
Correct me if im wrong but is this right when searching for poet meta key a value in Wordpress ?
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'clientorders',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'installDDate',
      'value' => $date1,
      'compare' => '=',
    ),
  ),
);


Your syntax is correct, if the query isn't coming up with anything it'd be worth checking for typos. Is that double D in installDDate deliberate?
The reason it uses nested arrays is to allow for more than one meta key/value pair in the query, which can be combined with different relations. Each pair would have its own array at the innermost level.

Hi Chris - Yeah the installDDate is current and is within the post type clientorders.
ive even tried
`$date44 = '09-06-2024';
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'clientorders',
'meta_query' => array(
array(
'key' => 'clientOrderDate',
'value' => $date44,
'compare' => '=',
),
),
);
$results = get_posts($args); // Corrected constructor call
if ($results->have_posts()) {
echo "Matching order date: $date44"; // Display searched date
echo "";
while ($results->have_posts()) {
$results->the_post();'
